# GitHub action including tsc

Tags: typescript, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to make a GH-Action file which builds my nodejs app and then deploys it.
the Problem is, that tsc works (at least it takes a while) but no /dist folder exists after building. the tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ES6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

and the part of the gh action file looks like this:

```
name: Build & Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: ['deploy']

  pull_request:
    branches: ['deploy']

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: install node v18
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: yarn install
        run: yarn install
      - name: tsc
        uses: icrawl/action-tsc@v1
      - name: List files in the workspace repository
        run: |
          ls ${{ github.workspace }}
      - name: List files in ./
        run: |
          ls ./
      - uses: a7ul/tar-action@v1.1.0
        with:
          command: c
          cwd: './'
          files: |
            citygml-tools-2.1.0/
            src/
#dist does not exist!?
            dist/
            tmp/
            .dockerignore
            Dockerfile
            package.json
            tsconfig.json
            captain-definition
          outPath: deploy.tar

      # - name: Deploy App to CapRover
      #   uses: caprover/deploy-from-github@v1.0.1
      #   with:
      #     server: '${{ secrets.CAPROVER_SERVER }}'
      #     app: '${{ secrets.APP_NAME }}'
      #     token: '${{ secrets.APP_TOKEN }}'

      - name: Deploy App to CapRover
        uses: caprover/deploy-from-github@v1.0.1
        with:
          server: '${{ secrets.CAPROVER_PFCACE_SERVER }}'
          app: '${{ secrets.APP_NAME }}'
          token: '${{ secrets.APP_PFCACE_TOKEN }}'
```

I tried listing the files in the folder with ls, but there is no dist folder (which I would expect after tsc finishes).

when I run tsc locally it does exactly this: building the app inside "./dist"

any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me is to replace the `uses: icrawl/action-tsc@v1` with `run: yarn tsc`